# Chrome doesn't display html5 video but plays audio

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

Apparently there is something wrong with my HTML page or there is a bug in chrome.  (I seriously doubt the later)  It does however manage to play in FF 18, and Safari 602

My page looks like the following,

**404.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>chrisrjones.com - 404 - File Not Found</title>
<body>
Nope.

<br />

<!-- first try HTML5 playback: if serving as XML, expand `controls` to `controls="controls"` and autoplay likewise       -->
<!-- warning: playback does not work on iPad/iPhone if you include the poster attribute! fixed in iOS4                   -->

<video width="274" height="256" autoplay>
    <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
  <source src="../files/ahah-mp4-2.mov" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="../files/ahah.webm" type="video/webm"> <!-- Chrome10+, Ffx4+, Opera10.6+ -->
  <source src="../files/ahah.ogv" type="video/ogv"> <!-- Firefox3.6+ / Opera 10.5+ -->
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
  <!-- source: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/object-tag-syntax-flash-professional.html -->

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you maybe provide a fiddle so others can check/test?

Comment: go to chrisrjones.com/whatever in the chrome browser, and the audio should play, but show no video.  ...funny thing is that I am using chrome on linux right now, and it works, but doesn't on os x

Comment: Works on my Win32 Chrome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file http://chrisrjones.com/files/ahah-mp4-2.mov is sendt with MIME type : video/quicktime.

Try sending it with MIME type : video/mp4.

And encode the video in H.264.

If it dont work in Internet explorer its proberly because the video aint encoded in H.264.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason if enable the "controls" feature of the video tag the video shows in chrome on OS X.  So far the only browser that doesn't show the video file is chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 for OS X.  I downloaded the latest vanilla copy of Chrome for Windows 7 and the video file showed.

Now all I have to do is figure out why the video file isn't playing in Internet Exploder *sigh*